# PHP Wont print after function called inside printf

Tags: php, html, sql

i've been struggling with this for 2 days now. I have a contacts page that shows you all the info for each database row in an html table. Along with this info i have stored on the DB the filenames of the files the user uploads. I want the file names to be printed as a list item inside the table row. I managed to print them and make them a downloadable link but i cant manage to print for each row its own files ( Stored by id both in db and folders). This is the code:

```
 <?php 
            $loop = function($myarray,$id){         
                foreach ($myarray as $ray){
                        print("<li><a href=\"./uploads/$id/$ray\">$ray</a></li>");

                };
            };
            foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, fathersname, mothersname, mobile, fixed1, fixed2, email, work, street, tk, city, files FROM contacts") as $row) {
                $query1 = ("SELECT files FROM contacts WHERE id=$row->id");
                $res = $dbh->query($query1);
                $serialized_arr = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $un_arr= unserialize($serialized_arr["files"]);

                printf("
                <tr>
                <td id=\"firstname$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"lastname$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"fathersname$row->id\"> %s </td> 
                <td id=\"mothersname$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"mobile$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"fixedone$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"fixedtwo$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"email$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"work$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"street$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"tk$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td id=\"city$row->id\"> %s </td>
                <td>
                     $loop($un_arr, $row->id)
                </td>
                <td> <button id=\"edit_button<?php echo $row->id;?>\" class=\"btn1\"  ><i class=\"fas fa-edit\"> </i> </button>        
                    <a href=\"delete.php?id=$row->id\" id=\"delete_button$row->id;?>\" class=\"btn1\"  onclick=\"return confirm('Είσαι Σίγουρος/η? Τα αρχεία που ανέβασες με την καταχώρηση δεν θα σβηστούν!');\" value=\"\"><i class=\"fas fa-trash\"></i></a>
                </td>
                </tr> " , $row->firstname, $row->lastname, $row->fathersname, $row->mothersname, $row->mobile, $row->fixed1, $row->fixed2, $row->email, $row->work, $row->street, $row->tk, $row->city

                );
            }
        ?>
```

This code get this error :  Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string.
If i change it to this 
                     `<td>
                        ". $loop($un_arr, $row->id)."
                      </td>`
    It prints the correct result but in the top left of the website and not inside the table. Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I cant understand what your code is doing, but try to learn and use join and group_concat it'll save you so much time.

Comment: Perhaps : $rows = $dbh->query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, fathersname, mothersname, mobile, fixed1, fixed2, email, work, street, tk, city, files FROM contacts")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: @Ash Thanks for your response. https://imgur.com/a/k12hZ this is the table with the info.The filenames that are on the top left must be in the tables last row, but i dont know how to do it. Everything else works like charm. Can you provide me with a source for join and group concat?

Comment: $rows = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM contacts");
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
      var_dump($row);
    }

Comment: can you replace your code with the following and send over whats in one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is trying to print the variable called `$loop`.

Since the closure (the same one mentioned in the error) assigned to it, takes care of `print`ing, just break up the original printf invocation!

```
printf("
    <tr>
         ...other cells here...
         <td id=\"city$row->id\"> %s </td>
         <td>
");

// Stop, at this point, and let your closure print the contents of the image cell!
$loop($un_arr, $row->id)

// Then, continue along with a new print statement!
printf(
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id=\"edit_button<?php echo $row->id;?>\" class=\"btn1\"  ><i class=\"fas fa-edit\"></i></button>        
        <a href=\"delete.php?id=$row->id\" id=\"delete_button$row->id;?>\" class=\"btn1\"  onclick=\"return confirm('Είσαι Σίγουρος/η? Τα αρχεία που ανέβασες με την καταχώρηση δεν θα σβηστούν!');\" value=\"\"><i class=\"fas fa-trash\"></i></a>
        </td>
        </tr>", $row->firstname, $row->lastname, $row->fathersname, $row->mothersname, $row->mobile, $row->fixed1, $row->fixed2, $row->email, $row->work, $row->street, $row->tk, $row->city
);
```